# Material UI Layout - 3 column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid

I want to design my layout something like this using material UI, I have look into it and thinking of using Grid component, but how do I implement something like this for the middle column into two rows??

[image: grid]

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example Code

I'm using Material UI's [`Grid` component](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout) in the following code.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  container: {
    height: "100%", // So that grids 1 & 4 go all the way down
    minHeight: 150, // Give minimum height to a div
    border: "1px solid black",
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  containerTall: {
    minHeight: 250 // This div has higher minimum height
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs>
        <div className={classes.container}>1</div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container direction="column" xs spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <div className={classes.container}>2</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>
          <div className={clsx(classes.container, classes.containerTall)}>
            3
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs>
        <div className={classes.container}>4</div>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit on Sandbox]

The above code will generate the following result:

[image: results]

### Explanation

The overall grid structure looks like:

```
<Grid container direction="row">
  <Grid item xs />
  <Grid item xs container direction="column">
    <Grid item xs />
    <Grid item xs />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs />
</Grid>
```

We first create a grid container with flex direction of row. Inside the container, we put 3 `Grid` item components so that they align from left to right. For the second (middle) `Grid` item, we also define it as a container with flex direction of column. Inside it, we place two `Grid` items such that one is on top and one is on bottom.

Note that particularly for grid 3's code, I added `className={clsx(classes.container, classes.containerTall)}`. This is basically saying that we would apply `classes.container` and `classes.containerTall` to this grid. You can [read this section](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#whats-the-clsx-dependency-for) on more about `clsx()`.

To make grid 3 slightly taller than grid 2, I've set the `minHeight` of grid 2 to be `150px` while the `minHeight` of grid 3 is set to be `250px`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto layout from here

https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#auto-layout

Structure should be

- Col
- Col
- ---- Row (3 size)
- ---- Row (3 size)
- Col